# How can I specify global and local chunk options for a quarto pdf book?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, quarto

I am trying to create a PDF book using Quarto. In particular, I want to know if there is a way to specify the global chunk options, which would be used for all the chunks in all the qmd pages. The global option is

```
echo = TRUE
```

(I think this syntax is in R Markdown, not Quarto.) But only for some code chunks in some of the pages, I want to hide the code (by setting echo = FALSE). How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **Setting Global Options**

In quarto documents, books or presentation, to set options like `echo`, `eval`, `warning`, `error`, `include`, `output` globally, we need to specify them under `execute` yaml key.

So in quarto book, to set echo to true globally, we set `echo: true` under `execute`.

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: book
  
execute: 
  echo: true

book:
  title: "Quarto book"
  author: "Jane Doe"
  date: "8/7/2022"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
```

### **Setting local options**

And setting these options locally (for some specific chunk in a specific qmd page) is same as r-markdown.

Say in my `index.qmd`, I can specify `echo=FALSE` for a chunk like this,

**index.qmd**

````
# Preface {.unnumbered}

This is a Quarto book.

To learn more about Quarto books visit <https://quarto.org/docs/books>.

```{r echo=FALSE}
1 + 1
```
````

Comment: I think the correct syntax for options in code cells (aka 'local options') in Quarto is starting each line with `#| `, for example:
```{r}\n
#| echo: false\n
1 + 1\n
```
see: https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html